# how can we make python to run a code if a condition is true and run another code if a condition is false

Tags: python-3.x

In this code I want to know that if the first_input == c condition is true then the remaining code(mentioned after the condition) should not be executed and another code(which is not mentioned) should be executed and if the condition is false this code(mentioned one) should be executed and the other one(unmentioned one) should not be executed 
If have not mentioned the other code

```
first_input = input()
if first_input == a:
    print("something")
elif first_input == b:
    print("Another")
elif first_input == c:
second_input = input()
if second_input == d:
    print("done")
```

Comment: I didn't really get the question, could you rephrase your question please ?

Comment: Please be clearer with what you need. What is your expected behavior? What is your code doing now? How are they different?

Comment: you want to know two different things with the same `True` condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Even if your question is not very clear you should try something like:

```
first_input = input()
if first_input == a:
    print("something")
elif first_input == b:
    print("Another")
elif first_input == c:
    #call your over function/code not mentioned here 
second_input = input()
if second_input == d:
    print("done")
```

It will do the job as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to check if `first_input` is equal to `c`, and if it is, execute a block of code.

The following program accomplishes that:

```
first_input = input()
if first_input == 'a':
        print("something")
elif first_input == 'b':
        print("Another")
elif first_input == 'c':
        second_input = input()
        if second_input == 'd':
                print("done")
        else:
                print("Second input did not equal d")
else:
        print("You did not enter a, b, or c")
```

This program works like below:

```
C:\Users\jerry\Desktop>python test.py
a
something

C:\Users\jerry\Desktop>python test.py
b
Another

C:\Users\jerry\Desktop>python test.py
c
d
done

C:\Users\jerry\Desktop>python test.py
c
e
Second input did not equal d

C:\Users\jerry\Desktop>python test.py
f
You did not enter a, b, or c

C:\Users\jerry\Desktop>
```

Comment: I want to just know that if I can execute the mentioned code after the condition if the condition is false and another code if the condition is true